# fusiongraphs in ruby on rails not showing graphs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, fusioncharts

I'm Implementing `fusiongraphs`to rails app.

I followed the instructions on https://www.fusioncharts.com/ruby-on-rails-charts/

I dont get an error I only get a blank "graph".

All my code is basically just a copy/paste from the instructional page.

I added the Js files to the `vendor/assets/javascripts/fusioncharts/` as told by the instructions.

I also added the Js files to the `app/assets/javascript/fusioncharts/`when the above didn't work.

This is my `index.html.erb`

```
<h3>My Chart</h3>
<%= @chart.render() %>
```

And in the controller I have.

```
class FusionsController < ApplicationController
 def index


@chart = Fusioncharts::Chart.new({
    width: "600",
    height: "400",
    type: "mscolumn2d",
    renderAt: "chartContainer",
    dataSource: {
        chart: {
        caption: "Comparison of Quarterly Revenue",
        subCaption: "Harry's SuperMart",
        xAxisname: "Quarter",
        yAxisName: "Amount ($)",
        numberPrefix: "$",
        theme: "fint",
        exportEnabled: "1",
        },
        categories: [{
                category: [
                    { label: "Q1" },
                    { label: "Q2" },
                    { label: "Q3" },
                    { label: "Q4" }
                ]
            }],
            dataset: [
                {
                    seriesname: "Previous Year",
                    data: [
                        { value: "10000" },
                        { value: "11500" },
                        { value: "12500" },
                        { value: "15000" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    seriesname: "Current Year",
                    data: [
                        { value: "25400" },
                        { value: "29800" },
                        { value: "21800" },
                        { value: "26800" }
                    ]
                }
          ]
    }
})



 end
end
```

this is my application.js file

```
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts
//= require fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts
//= require fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**UPDATE**

In the log there is this mesages.

```
Uncaught Error: #03091456 chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element.
    at C.core.render (fusioncharts.self-5632b79980c9442dbaf0af7af73571de800f2f3be1911577fd5b5e629b15b44e.js?body=1:78)
    at Function.<anonymous> ((index):45)
    at fusioncharts.self-5632b79980c9442dbaf0af7af73571de800f2f3be1911577fd5b5e629b15b44e.js?body=1:48
```

Here is a screenshot of the error messages:

[image]

Can anyone help my with this, I've been spending all morning to figure this out with no luck.

Comment: Any clues in the log?

Comment: @TomLord I added an update with the console messages. I'm too unexperienced to make something of it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a line, you need to add this line in your index.html.erb file

```
<div id="chartContainer"><%= @chart.render() %></div>
```

Comment: After that, if it is not working then you may contact support@fusioncharts.com They are very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, it seems like you didn't add container to render the charts. This will have HTML template required to render the chart -

```
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<%= @chart.render() %>
```

Controller file will have the chart constructor, attributes and the datasource required to render the chart -

```
require 'fusioncharts-rails'
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  # layout false
  def HomeView
    @chart = Fusioncharts::Chart.new({
        :height => 400,
        :width => 600,
        :id => 'chart',
        :type => 'MSColumn2D',
        :renderAt => 'chart-container',
        :dataSource => {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Countries With Most Oil Reserves [2017-18]",
                "subCaption": "In MMbbl = One Million barrels",
                "xAxisName": "Country",
                "yAxisName": "Reserves (MMbbl)",
                "numberSuffix": "K",
                "theme": "fusion",
            },
            "data": [{
                "label": "Venezuela",
                "value": "290"
            }, {
                "label": "Saudi",
                "value": "260"
            }, {
                "label": "Canada",
                "value": "180"
            }, {
                "label": "Iran",
                "value": "140"
            }, {
                "label": "Russia",
                "value": "115"
            }, {
                "label": "UAE",
                "value": "100"
            }, {
                "label": "US",
                "value": "30"
            }, {
                "label": "China",
                "value": "30"
            }]
        }
    end
end
```

Document reference - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/ruby-on-rails/your-first-chart-using-ruby-on-rails

Hope this would help you.